# Selenium 2 and Junit 4 testcase: Selecting options from drop down box with multiple class name

Tags: drop-down-menu, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I wanted to select and click one of the option which becomes visible through drop down list when the mouse moves to the text or visible text on a web page .

So basically I move the mouse to text "Browse" in the below html page and then I get a different options like "Pages", "Blog".

So in order to select or click "Browse" I use (in Selenium 2.21.0) :

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='browse-menu-link']/span")).click()`.

Is there a way that I can select the rest of the options without knowing their ids (as their ids can change or name can change).
Can I move and select different options by index?
I.e my requirement is there can be 4 options or 5 option in the drop down.I don't care about their name as long as they are under "Browse" Text.

In the html page, these hidden options which become visible when mouse moves or is clicked at "Browse" have class name as:

```
ajs-drop-down hidden
```

There are also other hidden options under some other drop down having same class name so selecting elements by class name gives error.

Here is the HTML code/page:

```
<head>
<body id="com-test" class="" onload="placeFocus()">
<div id="full-height-container">
<fieldset class="hidden parameters">
<fieldset class="hidden parameters">
<div id="header" class="">
<form id="quick-search" class="quick-search" action="/dosearchsite.action"     method="get">
<fieldset>
<legend>Quick Search</legend>
<input id="quick-search-query" class="quick-search-query placeholded" type="text"   size="25" name="queryString" autocomplete="off" accesskey="q">
<input id="quick-search-submit" class="quick-search-submit" type="submit"   value="Search">
<div class="aui-dd-parent quick-nav-drop-down"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="hidden parameters">
<input id="quickNavEnabled" type="hidden" value="true">
</fieldset>
</form >
<ul id="header-menu-bar" class="ajs-menu-bar">
<li class="normal ajs-menu-item">
<a id="browse-menu-link" class="browse trigger ajs-menu-title" href="#">
<span>
**<span>Browse</span>**
</span>
</a>
<div class="ajs-drop-down hidden" hidden="" style="">
<ul id="browse-menu-link-leading" class="section-leading first">
<li class="">
<a id="space-pages-link" class="" title="Attachments: 5" href="/pages/listpages.action?   key=UNI">
**<span>Pages</span>**
</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a id="space-blogposts-link" class="" title="Attachments: 5"   href="/pages/viewrecentblogposts.action?key=UNI">
**<span>Blog</span>**
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me just make sure: after hovering mouse on "Browse" link the items under < div class="ajs-drop-down hidden" hidden="" style=""> become visible and you want to get to them using indexes instead of any names?

In such case I would do the following

```
List<WebElemet> menuItems = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ajs-drop-down hidden']")).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
WebElement exampleItem = menuItems.get(1); //getting 2nd menu item
```

You can also play with some ugly xpath

```
WebElement exampleItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@className='ajs-drop-down hidden'/ul/li[1]/a]));
```

I recommend the first method however.

Now, you mentioned something about other options under other dropdowns. So i assume that locating appropriate div like in example above is not so straightforward. If that's the case we need to first locate the div using link's (a element) id.

```
List<WebElemet> menuItems = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='browse-menu-link']/../div")).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

That should yield the same results as the first example.

**EDIT**

If you want to find an element using just a part of class name, the xpath is your friend:

```
List<WebElemet> menuItems = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'hidden')]")).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

driver.findElement will return the first element that meets specified criteria. If you want to get 2nd or 3rd just use findElement**s** and get the element from the list (like in my first example above)

Comment: Hi JacekM ,thanks for your response.As I have same class name at other place I get the following error.How do I select element only from the first class or a specific order of the class:

Comment: The error is :
org.openqa.selenium.IllegalLocatorException: Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results.
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.By.className(By.java:132)
 at

Comment: The error is not caused by the fact that you have another class of that name. The error is a result of the fact that selenium does not allow for ' ' (spaces) in class names when searching by class name. One way to fix it is to use By.xpath instead of By.className. I've edited my first example and changed the selector to xpath, that should do the trick. Also read the edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example above.I wasnt sure of how to search for a particular string (ie. using contains in Selenium 2.0) .Can you cite more examples or provide a link to such sites.By the way when I use the code above,I now get :org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[contains(@class,'hidden'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
[InvalidSelectorError] Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(@class,'hidden'] because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal "

Comment: The error was a result of my mistake. ;) There was ')' missing before ']'. I've edited my answer, it should be ok now.

Comment: As for contains function - it's a part of xpath syntax, it's not related to Selenium. Basically the syntax is
//element[contains(@attribute, 'text')]
You can also use xpath functions instead of specific attribute:
//span[contains(text(), 'whatever')] - will search for every span tag that looks like < span >something whatever something< /span >

Comment: The code give does not select any elements when I use contains(@class, 'hidden') .

Comment: Thanks .The code here does not select any elements   Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='browse-menu-link']/span")).click(); //to make the elements visisble   
//the below code does nto display anything
List<WebElement> menuItems = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'hidden')]")).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement select : menuItems) {System.out.println(select);

Comment: When I use this code is does select something however it gives element not visible when I use click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='browse-menu-link']/span")).click();
 List<WebElement> menuItems1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ajs-drop-down hidden']")).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement select : menuItems1) {
System.out.println(select);
}
WebElement exampleItem = menuItems1.get(1);
exampleItem.click();